# Uvicorn + Gunicorn + Starlette is getting stuck when serving, can't restart the service without sigkill

Tags: python, gunicorn, supervisord, uvicorn, starlette

I am serving a model on a VM through gunicorn + uvicorn.

It is automatically started by supervisord, running `api.sh`.

`api.sh` contains:

```
source /home/asd/.virtual_envs/myproject/bin/activate

/home/asd/.virtual_envs/myproject/bin/gunicorn --max-requests-jitter 30 -w 6 -b 0.0.0.0:4080 api:app -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
```

Without getting too much into `api.py`, it contains these main parts:

```
from starlette.applications import Starlette
from models import SomeModelClass


app = Starlette(debug=False)
model = SomeModelClass()


@app.route('/do_things', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'HEAD'])
async def add_styles(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        params = request.query_params
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        params = await request.json()
    elif request.method == 'HEAD':
        return UJSONResponse([])

    # Doing things
    result = model(params)
    return UJSONResponse(result)
```

What happens is that I start getting these errors after the api is up for a few days:

```
[INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.3
[ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 4080)
[ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 4080)
[ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 4080)
[ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[ERROR] Connection in use: ('0.0.0.0', 4080)
[ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
...
```

Restarting api in supervisord does nothing, I get the same messages as above. The only way I found that works is:

1. Stop api in supervisord
2. See which pid is running on 4080 port (a `python3.8` process): `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN`
3. Kill it running `kill -9 [PID]`
4. Repeat steps 2-3 for 1-2 times till nothing takes up the 4080 port
5. Start the api in supervisord

Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code actually used `Pool` from `multiprocessing` and that is most likely what caused this issue.

Example:

```
from starlette.applications import Starlette
from models import SomeModelClass
from multiprocessing import Pool
from utils import myfun


app = Starlette(debug=False)
model = SomeModelClass()


@app.route('/do_things', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'HEAD'])
async def add_styles(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        params = request.query_params
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        params = await request.json()
    elif request.method == 'HEAD':
        return UJSONResponse([])

    # Doing things
    result = model(params)
    # Start of the offending code
    pool = Pool(4)
    result = pool.map(myfun, result, chunksize=1)
    # End of the offending code
    return UJSONResponse(result)
```

The solution for that is to replace `multiprocessing` with `concurrency`:

```
from starlette.applications import Starlette
from models import SomeModelClass
import concurrent.futures
from utils import myfun


app = Starlette(debug=False)
model = SomeModelClass()


@app.route('/do_things', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'HEAD'])
async def add_styles(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        params = request.query_params
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        params = await request.json()
    elif request.method == 'HEAD':
        return UJSONResponse([])

    # Doing things
    result = model(params)
    # Start of the fix
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
        result = executor.map(myfun, result)
    result = list(result)
    # End of the fix
    return UJSONResponse(result)
```